# Bruteforce takes more time than binary search to find the first element of a sorted list

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I'm relatively new to python, so I'm not big on the efficieny aspect of it, which is why, when I wrote two algorithms to search for an element, I was surprised

```
''' 
Making an array with data that can be stored easily
Setting up pointers in data using lists


 '''

import time

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] #starting / defining the array i need for the binary seach to work
process_arr = []
ctr = 0


def ARR_SEARCH(INPUT):
    start = time.time()
    # Have to set R and L in order to find the middle element of this
    l = 0
    r = len(arr)-1
    mid = None
    returntup = None
    while r > l:
        mid = (l+ (r-l))//2 # The R - L is to ensure that it is the mid
        if(arr[mid] == INPUT):
            end = time.time() - start
            r = 0
            returntup = mid, end
        elif(arr[mid] > INPUT):

            r = mid-1

        elif(arr[mid] < INPUT):

            l = mid+1

    if returntup!=None:
        return returntup
    else:
        return -1, 0


def binarySearch (arr, l, r, x): 
    start = time.time()
    # Check base case 
    if r >= l: 

        mid = l + (r - l)//2

        # If element is present at the middle itself 
        if arr[mid] == x: 
            end = time.time() - start
            print("BINARY END ", end)
            returntup = mid, end
            return returntup

        # If element is smaller than mid, then it  
        # can only be present in left subarray 
        elif arr[mid] > x: 
            return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x) 

        # Else the element can only be present  
        # in right subarray 
        else: 
            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x) 

    else: 
        # Element is not present in the array 
        return -1

def BRUTE_FORCE_v2(INPUT):
    start = time.time()
    ctr = -1
    for i in arr:
        ctr += 1
        if i==INPUT:
            end = time.time() - start
            print("BRUTE END" , end)
            returntup = ctr, end
            return returntup
        else:
            continue
    else:
        end = time.time() - start
        returntup = -1, end
        return returntup


def BRUTE_FORCE(INPUT):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i]==INPUT:
            end = time.time() - start
            returntup = i, end
            return returntup
        else:
            continue
    else:
        end = time.time() - start
        returntup = -1, end
        return returntup

search = int(input("Enter the required search element"))
out1 = BRUTE_FORCE(search)
out2 = binarySearch(arr, 0, (len(arr)-1), search)
out3 = BRUTE_FORCE_v2(search)
diff1 = out1[1] - out2[1]
diff2 = out1[1] - out3[1]
diff3 = out3[1] - out2[1]
print("Brute vs Force Ratio in this case is: \n \n ", diff1)
print("\n \n \n \n ")
print("The difference between the normal and the upgraded brute force algorithm in this case is: \n \n", diff2)
print("\n \n \n \n ")
print("So, the effective time differnece between the two actual algs are: \n \n ", diff3)
```

The output of this program is as follows

```
Enter the required search element8

BINARY END  1.430511474609375e-06

BRUTE END 2.6226043701171875e-06

Brute vs Force Ratio in this case is:

5.7220458984375e-06 

The difference between the normal and the upgraded brute force algorithm in this case is:
 4.5299530029296875e-06 

So, the effective time differnece between the two actual algs are:

 1.1920928955078125e-06
```

This makes perfect sense, even for a small list, binary search trumps out bruteforce

BUT

What's interesting here is when I search for the element '1'

1 is in the beginning of the list, and bruteforce, should ideally, find it first. BUT binary search somehow beats it

My output, when I search for 1, is this

```
Enter the required search element1

BINARY END  1.430511474609375e-06

BRUTE END 2.86102294921875e-06

Brute vs Force Ratio in this case is: 

5.245208740234375e-06 

The difference between the normal and the upgraded brute force algorithm in this case is: 3.814697265625e-06 
So, the effective time differnece between the two actual algs are: 
1.430511474609375e-06
```

If you were wondering why there are two bruteforce algorithms, one is for the python implementation of iterating through lists, and one is the regular array parsing implementation

Im calculating the difference between the python implementation of list parsing, as it looks to be faster than the other implementation, and finding the difference between the times.

As a fact, simple because the bruteforce has to make only one comparison, it has to be faster than the binary search, but why isn't it?

Could someone answer the question?

PS: This code does not play well with idle, and it outputs 0.0 for all end times. Terminal seems to give the right output though....

Comment: Don't use `time.time()` for this - it is not as accurate as `time.perf_counter()`. Better yet, use the `timeit` library. The times you are measuring are so small that clock error likely dominates them; to get reliable results you should run the algorithm many times and then divide by the number of repetitions.

Comment: As a demonstration of how inaccurate the clock you're using is, note that your second measurement is *exactly twice* the first measurement. The chance of that happening if all those decimal places were accurate is tiny; what's actually happened is that one algorithm completed in (say) one tick of the clock, and the other one took two ticks.

Comment: `mid = (l+ (r-l))//2` is parenthesized wrong.

Comment: ah, in ARR_INPUT? or in binarySearch?. Because I believe the implementation in binarySearch is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @kaya3

This was indeed a clock error. It looks like the first result was by pure chance, and checking this out for a larger number of iterations, or using the libraries mentioned gives the desired values.